# How do I change UID of 0 from non-root user?

Tags: root, user, uid

I have set the UID of user01 to be 0 when I created it.  Now I am trying to delete the user and it complains "user01 is currently logged in".  I check the process list, and that doesn't seem to be true.  However, root (which also has UID of 0) has processes running.  How can I delete user01?  I also tried changing UID of user01 with usermod, with no luck.

Comment: How are you trying to delete the user exactly? What operating system is this?

Comment: This is Linux: 3.14.42-31.38.amzn1.x86_64 . Used command "userdel user01"

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with:

```
sed -i '/user01/d' {passwd,shadow}
```

Comment: Followed by rm -r /home/user01 to get rid of their home directory !  (James, Adams command deletes the entry from the password and shadow files, effectively killing that user)

Comment: This worked! I needed to run this at /etc directory.